# How to save a variable in database in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables in database and two controllers in cakephp, UsersController and DatasController. I wanna save authenticated user`s id in datas table.
Here is my code ...

```
class DatasController extends AppController{
     public function adddam(){
     $uid=$this->Auth->user('id');
    $datas = $this->Datas->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $datas = $this->Datas->newEntity();
        $this->request->data['user_id'] =$uid;
        $datas = $this->Datas->patchEntity($datas, $this->request->data);
        $this->Datas->save($datas);
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work correctly.Are there somethings else that I forget?

Answer (score 0):

I gather that you're using **CakePhp3** then try this structure to Add 'Datas'

```
class DatasController extends AppController {

    public function adddam() { 

        $uid = $this->Auth->User()['id'];

        $datas = $this->Datas->newEntity();

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $datas = $this->Datas->patchEntity($datas, $this->request->data);

            $datas['user_id'] = $uid;

            if($this->Datas->save($datas)) 
            {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The datas has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'adddam']); //Redirect when you want

            } else {

                $this->Flash->error(__('The datas could not be saved. Please, try again.'));

            }

        }

        $this->set(compact('datas'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['datas']);
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work I tested it but every fields inserted on table Except user_id. :(

Comment: Try `debug` **$uid** to see if it´s have value or just put `$datas['user_id'] = 1`  and check if your table has `user_id` field and let me know the results.

Comment: I used print_r($data) and out put is App\Model\Entity\Damage Object ( [floor] => 1 [place] => 1 [describtion] => abc [date] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object ( [time] => 2016-07-20T08:32:37+00:00 [timezone] => UTC [fixedNowTime] => ) [user_id] => 5 [[new]] => 1 [[accessible]] => Array ( [*] => 1 ) [[dirty]] => Array ( [floor] => 1 [place] => 1 [describtion] => 1 [date] => 1 [user_id] => 1 )